# How to industry standard sculpt in blender?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, retopology, remesh

there are rumors out there that blender isn't capable of handling high resolution 3d models , and yes this is true at 10 - 15 mil vertisies blender isn't reliable for sculpting anymore I've tested every imaginable workflow that was out there i didn't find out how it could be done .

my purpose of using blender is for traditional woodworking and modeling furniture made of wood , the problem is i don't have time for retopology and my models ain't gonna move either , another problem is blender can not handle high resolution models so my models came out low quality , once i thought it could be a memory problem with my pc so i upgraded that to a 32gb ddr5 memory but same scenario happens , blender just can't , the voxel remesh ruins the surface quality , dyntopo isn't stable after 1 mil , im stuck! im gonna change software ! after all this I've been thru , after all this time i spent to learn blender , neither quadremesher or instant meshes and multiresolution workflow can help because of lack of adaptivity and highres final result , can't tell the name of the software but 100 mil mesh can be handled on that one with my older 8gb ram pc like a charm ! and decimation to 1 or 2 mi mesh happens in a blink of an eye !

nut inside blender , decimating a 15 mil mesh to a 1 mil , will crash ! thats it !

what is my way ? i want to stay loyal to the software i don't want to change it please if someone had experience on such stuff please help ! what should i do ?

aren't blender programmers made blender hardware hungry or limited on purpose ?

Comment: `there are rumors` no rumors, just facts. `aren't blender programmers made blender hardware hungry or limited on purpose ?` It's not a conspiracy. Just different purposes in mind. ZBrush or 3Dcoat don't use the same technologies to handle and display models, but they are mostly just for sculpting. Blender is a 3D production swiss army knife. Don't expect a swiss army knife to perform like a chainsaw.

Comment: i do have access in both softwares that you have mentioned and comparing them with blender in sculpting , in my opinion blender is more super powerful than them , idk it may was me but the final product should've been retopologyzed anyways and the sculpted mesh isn't gonna be the final result , but there is a thing when im working with a mesh that the other parts are sculpted the other areas shouldn't take effect but why dyntopo still lags ?

Answer (score 3):

It's important to keep in mind that 3D modeling software, including Blender, is designed to handle a wide range of use cases and may not be optimized for every specific workflow or task. It's possible that your high-resolution models may be more resource-intensive than Blender can handle, and that may be causing issues with sculpting and decimation. You also can try other software like Solidworks or Inventor. Another solution would be cloud computing to scale the computing abilities. I did not tried it but scaleable Systems are worth a try if you have the money or you are a student.

Comment: Sir i know nothing about softwares that mentioned in comments above , i have tested out zbrush quite a bit but sculptrispro (duntop in blender) is unstable after 1 mil ish polys this is a good sign that blender is a good software , i researched alot it seems like sculpted mesh is not the final industry standard file